# How to follow schedule stored in DB for running cron jobs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have developed a website for auto posting on twitter i have made generic contents for posting that i will replace with some parameters while posting and stored a posting schedule in DB. Now my question is how i can run cron jobs so that my posting schedule should follow and no posting schedule miss. if i run posting code through cron job after each 30 minutes then what if any posting schedule in this thirty minutes interval that will surely miss the posting.

I hope my question is clear if not kindly ask.

Comment: Run cron job every minute, check for database if there is a need to post a new tweet if so make that happen otherwise just do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problems solution is easy.

---

- create a cron which will hit your db in every minute ( or any amount of time that you want to keep).
- maintain a `time_interval` and `cron_executed`  ( default value 0) and `post`  fields in your db.
- check your database for a time interval. the time interval will hold the time if the time matches the current time. or exceeds that time then execute the cron. and post the values from post on twitter. and mark cron_executed as 1. so its not executed in near future.